# How to compute spin image descriptors with pcl

Tags: c++, image-processing, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud using the c++ `pcl` library and I would like to compute the spin image descriptor for each point. I have tried with the implemanted `SpinImageEstimation` class in `pcl` but I get a histogram way larger that it should be. For example with a spin image width of `8`, I get a histogram of size `153`. But I would like to have the `8x8` spin image.

Do you know how I should proceed for this?

ps: for reference on the spin image descriptor, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262885698000742

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you think the spin image is 8x8. See equation `(2)` in the paper: the spin image is rectangular because the points can lie on the positive or negative side of the normal. If you set the spin image width/bin count to 8, the image will be (2*8+1)x(8+1), which equals 153, the histogram size.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I don't know how to get the square images like in figures 1 and 3, from the histograms

Comment: I think those 10x10 images in Figure 1 are just meant to be general examples, and are not supposed to depict the spin images described later. In Figure 3 I don't see any square images, only the rectangular spin-images with aspect ratio 2:1 (roughly). I think the spin-images are just stored row-by-row in the 153-histograms.